# QLPreviewController showing file then going blank in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, quicklook

I've added a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` for UIKit's `QLPreviewController` which I've found in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357888/qlpreviewcontroller-missing-navigation-bar-in-swiftui):

```swift
struct QuickLookView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var url: URL
    var onDismiss: (() -> Void) = { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UINavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        (viewController.topViewController as? QLPreviewController)?.reloadData()
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        controller.reloadData()
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
        var parent: QuickLookView
        
        init(_ qlPreviewController: QuickLookView) {
            self.parent = qlPreviewController
            super.init()
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
             1
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            self.parent.url as QLPreviewItem
        }
    }
}
```

In my app, I download a file (jpg/png/pdf) via Alamofire:

```swift
let destination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.documentsDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent(document.id.string)
        .appendingPathComponent(document.name ?? "file.jpg")
    return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}
AF
    .download(url, to: destination)
    .responseURL { (response) in
        guard let url = response.fileURL else { return }
        self.fileURL = url
        self.isShowingDoc = true
    }
```

...and pass its local url to the `QuickLookView` to present it:

```swift
@State private var isShowingDoc = false
@State private var fileURL: URL?

var body: some View {
    // ...
    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDoc, onDismiss: { isShowingDoc = false }) {
        QuickLookView(url: fileURL!) {
            isShowingDoc = false
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that the `QuickLookView` opens as sheet, the file flashes (is displayed for like 0.1 seconds) and then the view goes blank:

[image]

I checked the `Documents` folder of the app in Finder and the file is there and matches the url passed to the `QuickLookView`. I've noticed that when the view is open, and I then delete the file from the folder via Finder, then the view will throw an error saying there's no such file – that means it did read it properly before it was deleted.

Note: I read somewhere that the QL controller has had issues when placed inside a navigation controller. In my view hierarchy, my views are embedded inside a `NavigationView` – might that cause issues?

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can u share the way you're passing the local url

Comment: This works with a local pdf, png, jpeg, gif files, everything seems to work fine

Comment: @cedricbahirwe I've updated my post and included a summarized version of how I fetch the file & pass the url.  Again, the file shows up in Finder and when I print the url, it correctly takes me to the file.

Comment: You are probably creating the view before completing the download

Comment: How would I change that? Wrap `QuickLookView(url: fileURL!)` inside an `if` statement? @LeoDabus Tried, but doesn't work...

Comment: I did manage to do that using an EmptyView

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Care to elaborate?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bra85lqrvp70ay8/QuickLook%20Preview%20SwiftUI.zip?dl=1

Comment: @LinusGeffarth did you notice that you need to update the button title for it to work? I am still investigating why I need to do that in order for it to work

Comment: Note also that QuickLookView's dismiss closure is never called at least on my implementation. sheet onDismiss works fine

Comment: Yes, thank you for the sample code. I debugged it down to finding the same thing about the button title. It doesn't apply to my code though, and I'm still looking into that as well...thanks for your help!

Comment: I got it to work with a simplified & mixed version of your and my code. I'll post that as an answer, although you should post it so I can accept your answer :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got it to work – big thanks to [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) for his help in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619376/qlpreviewcontroller-showing-file-then-going-blank-in-swiftui?noredirect=1#comment119529291_67619376).
Here's my currently working code:

```swift
@State private var isShowingDoc = false
@State private var isLoadingFile = false
@State private var fileURL: URL?

var body: some View {
    Button {
        let destination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.documentsDirectory
                .appendingPathComponent(document.id.string)
                .appendingPathComponent(document.name ?? "file.jpg")
            return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }
        isLoadingFile = true
        AF
            .download(url, to: destination)
            .responseURL { (response) in
                self.isLoadingFile = false
                guard let url = response.fileURL else { return }
                isShowingDoc = true
                self.fileURL = url
            }
    } label: {
        VStack {
            Text("download")
            if isLoadingFile {
                ActivityIndicator(style: .medium)
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDoc, onDismiss: { isShowingDoc = false }) {
        QuickLookView(url: fileURL!)
    }
}
```

with this `QuickLookView`: (mostly unchanged)

```swift
struct QuickLookView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var url: URL
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UINavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        (viewController.topViewController as? QLPreviewController)?.reloadData()
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        controller.reloadData()
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
        var parent: QuickLookView
        
        init(_ qlPreviewController: QuickLookView) {
            self.parent = qlPreviewController
            super.init()
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
             1
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            self.parent.url as QLPreviewItem
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's hardly any difference to my code from when I asked the question. Yesterday night, the `fileURL` was always `nil` for an unclear reason; yet, now it started working just fine. In exchange, the remote images in my list (not shown here) stopped working even though I haven't touched them, haha.

I don't know what's going on and what I even changed to make it work, but it works and I won't complain!

Comment: @LeoDabus the activity indicator here seems to act like your button title, making sure it works...

Answer (score 3):

You just need to update the view before presenting the sheet otherwise it wont work. It can be the button title, opacity or anything. Although it looks like a hack it works fine. I will be very glad if someone explains why it happens and if there is a proper way to make it work without updating the view.

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fileURL: URL!
    @State private var isDisabled = false
    @State private var isDownloadFinished = false
    @State private var buttonTitle: String = "Download PDF"
    private let url = URL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxrhk6194lf0n73/macpro_mid2010-macpro_mid2012.pdf?dl=1")!
    var body: some View {
        Button(buttonTitle) {
            isDisabled = true
            buttonTitle = "Downloading..."
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { location, response, error in
                guard
                    let location = location, error == nil,
                    let suggestedFilename = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.suggestedFilename,
                    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
                else { return }
                fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(suggestedFilename)
                if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: fileURL)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    isDownloadFinished = true
                    buttonTitle = ""  // you need to change the view prefore presenting the sheet otherwise it wont work
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        .disabled(isDisabled == true)
        .sheet(isPresented: $isDownloadFinished) {
            isDisabled = false
            isDownloadFinished = false
            fileURL = nil
            buttonTitle = "Download PDF"
        } content: {
            if isDownloadFinished {
                PreviewController(previewItems: [PreviewItem(url: fileURL, title: fileURL?.lastPathComponent)], index: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

---

```
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook

struct PreviewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var previewItems: [PreviewItem] = []
    
    var index: Int
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { .init(self) }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UINavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        (viewController.topViewController as? QLPreviewController)?.reloadData()
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        controller.reloadData()
        return .init(rootViewController: controller)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate {
        let previewController: PreviewController
        init(_ previewController: PreviewController) {
            self.previewController = previewController
        }
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            previewController.previewItems.count
        }
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            previewController.previewItems[index]
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class PreviewItem: NSObject, QLPreviewItem {
    var previewItemURL: URL?
    var previewItemTitle: String?
    init(url: URL? = nil, title: String? = nil) {
        previewItemURL = url
        previewItemTitle = title
    }
}
```